# Connect PostgreSQL to rabbitMQ

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq

I'm trying to get RabbitMQ to monitor a postgresql database to create a message queue when database rows are updated. The eventual plan is to feed this message queue into an AWS EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) cluster as a job.

I've read many many approaches to this but they are still confusing as a newcomer to RabbitMQ and many seemed to be written more than 5 years ago so I'm not sure if they'll still work with current versions of postgres and rabbitmq.

I've followed [this guide](https://area-51.blog/2017/02/11/publishing-messages-to-rabbitmq-from-postgresql/) about installing the area51/notify-rabbit docker container which can connect the two via a node app, but when I ran the docker container it immediately stopped and didn't seem to do anything.

There is also [this guide](https://www.compose.com/articles/going-from-postgresql-rows-to-rabbitmq-messages/), which uses a go app to connect the two, but I'd rather not use Go ouside of a docker container.

Additionally, there is also [this method](https://awide.io/postresql-and-rabbitmq/), to install the `pg_amqp` extension from a repository which hasn't been updated in years, which allows for a direct connection from PostgreSQL to RabbitMQ. However, when I followed this and attempted to install `pg_amqp` on my Postgres db (postgresql 12), I was unable to connect using `psql` to the database, getting the classic error:

```
 psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

My current set-up, is I have a rabbitMQ server installed in a docker container in an AWS EC2 instance which I can access via the internet. I ran the following to install and run it:

```
docker pull rabbitmq:3-management
docker run --rm -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

The postgresql database is running on a separate EC2 instance and both instances have the required ports open for accessing data from each server.

I have also looked into using Amazon SQS as well for this, but it didn't seem to have any info on linking Postgresql up to it. I haven't really seen any guides or Stack Overflow questions on this since 2017/18 so I'm wondering if this is still the best way to create a message broker for a kubernetes system? Any help/pointers on this much appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a trigger in pl/python that calls the RabbitMQ API?  Or maybe use the http extension (https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http)?

Comment: Just a comment. PostgreSQL is transactional and RabbitMQ is not. You probably should consider that the process may lose messages once in a while and the end user should be OK with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided the best thing to do was create some simple Python scripts to do the LISTEN/NOTIFY steps and route traffic from PostgreSQL to RabbitMQ based off the following code https://gist.github.com/kissgyorgy/beccba1291de962702ea9c237a900c79

I set it up inside Docker containers and set them to run in my Kubernetes cluster so they are within the automatic restarts if they fail.